# clientpeoplepicker property is not working

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, people-picker

Here is My code.

```
<td>
    <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker VisibleSuggestions="5" Rows="1" ID="ppContractManager" 
    Enabled="true"   Required="true" runat="server" 
    ValidationEnabled="true" AllowMultipleEntities="true" Width="245px" />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="true" Display="None" 
    ValidationGroup="QC" ID="rfvppContractManager" ControlToValidate="ppContractManager" 
    runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"   ValidateEmptyText="true"
    ErrorMessage="Enter Contract Manager" />
</td>
```

[image]

Here i typed user name and i will click save button its working fine.In contract manager field i didn't enter anything and i will click save button its showing alert Enter Contract Manager.

But when i entered George or any user name and i removed this name & i will click save button its saving with empty value.

Once i entered name in people-picker its assuming its not empty so when i removed the name still its assuming the field is not Empty so its not showing alert message.Once i entered name after refreshing only it will work fine otherwise its saving with empty value.how to solve this please anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint:PeopleEditor control in place of SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker.

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="user" runat="server" SelectionSet="User" AllowEmpty="false" Enabled="false" MultiSelect="false" ValidatorEnabled="false"/>
```

[to get value from PeopleEditor control.](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/SharePoint-PeopleEditor-Control-1696.php)

Comment: using this SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker only i did my full code. if i use people editor then i should change everything. Can you please tell me using clientpeople picker is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function plpckProjectSponsorFun() {
    var err = "";
    var pickval = document.getElementById('<%=ppContractManager.ClientID%>' + "_hiddenSpanData").value;
    if (pickval != "" && pickval != "&#160;" && pickval != "&nbsp;" && pickval != " ") {
        var v1 = Page_ClientValidate("QC");
        if (!v1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Call this plpckProjectSponsorFun() on button click

Comment: i tried this code but is not working i call this method in button click.